# jquery clone with HTML template

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, clone

I have seen a few tutorials on jQuery templates , which as far as I understand is outdataed , so I am trying to use .Clone I got it to work fine when I am only showing one result, but when I want to show an entire list of results it is not working, I am sure because of my bad jQuery.  I want to clone the entire .template class fill it from each member of the response array , then add each newly cloned template to #fillresultsdiv , if anyone can help find what I'm doing wrong

here is jQuery:

```
                 success: function (msg) {
                    var events = [];
                    var obj = $.parseJSON(msg.d);
                    $(obj.res).each(function () {
                        var newRow = $('.template').clone()
                        newRow.$('.day').text($(this).attr('day')),
                            newRow.$('.dayofweek').text($(this).attr('dayofweek')),
                            newRow.$('.month').text($(this).attr('month')),
                            newRow.$('.title').text($(this).attr('title')),
                            newRow.$('.time').text($(this).attr('time')),
                        newRow.$('.venue').text($(this).attr('venue')),
                        newRow.$('.description').text($(this).attr('description'))
                        $('#fillresultsdiv').append(newRow);
```

Here is a sample response :

```
   d: "{"res":[{"day":"26","dayofweek":"Tue","month":"Jun","title":"Glen Hansard","venue":"Vic Theatre","time":"7:00 PM","ticketurl":"http://seatgeek.com/glen-hansard-t
```

and here is my template HTML:

```
    <div class="Template">
      <div class="accordian_head1">
        <div class="date_container">
          <a class="day"></a><br/><br/>
          <a class="dayofweek"></a><br/>
          <a class="month"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="title_container">
          <a class="title">Title</a>
          <a class="venue"><br/></a><a class="time"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="links">
          <a href=" + dr(36).ToString() + ?aid=854">Buy Tickets</a><br/>
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="fnAddToCalendar({ 'eventID' : '  dr(0).ToString() + '});">Watch</a><br/>
        <a href="#">Email</a><br/>
        <a href=""Calendar.aspx"">Calendar</a><br/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordian_body1new"><a class="description"></a>
  </div>
```

This is all #fillresultsdiv is

```
     <div id="fillresultsdiv"></div>
```

Comment: Where is your #fillresultsdiv in the html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Parse the entire string, because `msg` is not an object,
// so you can't use `msg.d`
var obj = $.parseJSON( msg );

$( obj.d.res ).each( function() {
    var newRow = $( '.template' ).clone();

    // Now loop through the object
    for ( var prop in this ) {
        if ( this.hasOwnProperty( prop ) ) {

            // Lucky for you, the keys match the classes :)
            $( '.' + prop, newRow ).text( this[ prop ] );
        }
    }
    $( '#fillresultsdiv' ).append( newRow );
} );
```

But you should definitely use a `DocumentFragment` to speed up the DOM manipulation and append everything at once. Because remember: **the DOM is effin slow**.

```
var obj = $.parseJSON( msg );

// Create a DocumentFragment
var el = document.createDocumentFragment();
$( obj.d.res ).each( function() {
    var newRow = $( '.template' ).clone();
    for ( var prop in this ) {
        if ( this.hasOwnProperty( prop ) ) {
            $( '.' + prop, newRow ).text( this[ prop ] );
        }
    }

    // Append to the DocumentFragment
    $( el ).append( newRow );
} );

// And append the DocumentFragment to the DIV
$( '#fillresultsdiv' ).append( el );
```

Comment: this looks like a way nicer way to do this , I can not get it to work though , it is going through if ( this.hasOwnProperty( prop ) ) { and prop is set to the correct property , but after that nothing is getting added to '#fillresultsdiv'  - even if $( '.' + this, newRow ).text( this[ prop ] ); was doing nothing , I should be getting black templates added , here nothing is being added

Comment: @ScottSelby yep, I corrected to use `$( '.' + prop )` instead of `$( '.' + this )`, my bad. `this` is not a string, but an object, which is why it failed.

Comment: ok, I kind of got it working , for some reason though it is showing the same results over and over again , I double check JSON and each event is only recieved once , but in this loop  - i displays the first result once , the second twice, the third 4 times, the forth 8 times, the fifth 16 times, and it turns into a weird binary math problem

Comment: Uh? Did you copy this code? Is there anything you changed? Sounds like a weird problem.

Comment: yes I copied and pasted it , this is also happening with the answer above  where there is no loop , so I'm thinking it is a problem with $( obj.res ).each( function() {

Comment: @ScottSelby oh, I edited, look at the beginning of my answer :)

Comment: that last edit did not work, i either get multiple responses or with the last edit nothing

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
          success: function (msg) {
                var events = [];
                var obj = $.parseJSON(msg.d);
                $(obj.res).each(function () {
                    var newRow = $('.template').clone();
                    newRow.find('.day').text($(this).attr('day'));
                    newRow.find('.dayofweek').text($(this).attr('dayofweek'));
                    newRow.find('.month').text($(this).attr('month'));
                    newRow.find('.title').text($(this).attr('title'));
                    newRow.find('.time').text($(this).attr('time'));
                    newRow.find('.venue').text($(this).attr('venue'));
                    newRow.find('.description').text($(this).attr('description'));
                    newRow.appendTo('#fillresultsdiv');
                  }
```

Comment: didn't work - I'm not too sure that  newRow.$('.day').text($(this).attr('day')), is proper jQuery

Comment: @ewein you're a developer. When you see so much repetition, try to do something about it :) Also, using commas instead of semicolons is not going to help your code.

Comment: I wanted to give an answer similar to his method so he would understand it easier. And yes the commas must go, I didn't notice them till now.